# re-submit the app when in ready for sale

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We currently have a predicament..

Our app has successfully gone through the certifications and is `ready for sale` and will launch next week.

We now realised that we want to change the icon on the home screen and the loading image which will require a re-submission…

- Is it possible to do in parallel with the current app that is going
  for sale? ie. can I make the change and submit the app again without
  effecting the existing app.
- And if the new app fails submission will this effect the existing app
  that is about to be launched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't remember for sure if you're allowed to submit another version of an app that's not for sale yet but I think you can. It's easy to tell, if you can there will be an "add version" button on the main page for managing your app in iTunes connect.

Assuming you can add another version, then the new version failing will not effect the approved version.

If you can't add another version, then you will have to reject your current version to resubmit, in which case the new version failing would put you back at square 0, you would have to resubmit again. Also, you would not be able to release until the new version is approved, so it's possible that even if you have no problems it wouldn't be approved by next week.